# Can't seem to find resources about testing a Cycle.js app

Tags: javascript, testing, web, reactive-programming, cyclejs

I have been trying to search for guide about testing a Cycle.js app but couldn't seem to find one. Can someone please point me to a guide or provide some examples?

Answer (score 4):

From [Cycle.js.org](http://cycle.js.org/):

> Sources and sinks can be easily used as [Adapters and Ports](https://iancooper.github.io/Paramore/ControlBus.html). This also means **testing is mostly a matter of feeding inputs and inspecting the output**. No deep mocking needed. Your application is just a pure transformation of data.

Indeed, from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cyclejs/core/issues/163) from Cycle.js core, author of Cycle.js André Staltz explains that:

> Testing Cycle.js code is basically just about **testing Observables**

The simplest test take the form:

```
// Create the mocked user events
const userEvents = mockDOMSource(...);

// Use them in your tests against `main`
const sinks = main({DOM: userEvents});

sinks.DOM.subscribe(function (vtree) {
  // make assertions here on the vtree
});
```

Notice that here we use `mockDOMSource`.
rx.js v5.3.0 released `mockDOMResponse`, that was later renamed to `mockDOMSource`. It is a function that makes it easy to mock user interactions (mock out intentions like `DOM.select('.foo').events('click')`).

Here is an [example](https://github.com/brentburg/cycle-examples/blob/bccece6515796b596c9b1d9af3a311990cb5776b/example-2/test.js):

```
test('CounterButton should increment number by 1 when clicked', t => {
  t.plan(4)
  const DOM = mockDOMSource({'.inc': {click: Observable.repeat({}, 3)}})
  const sinks = CounterButton({DOM})
  sinks.DOM
    .take(4)
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(vtrees => {
      const counts = vtrees.map(vt => vt.children[0].text.match(/\d+$/)[0])
      t.equal(counts[0], '0', 'button has count 0')
      t.equal(counts[1], '1', 'button has count 1')
      t.equal(counts[2], '2', 'button has count 2')
      t.equal(counts[3], '3', 'button has count 3')
    })
})
```

If you search for globally in GitHub for `mockDOMSource` [here](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=mockDOMSource&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and `mockDOMResponse` [here](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=mockDOMResponse&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)
then you can [find](https://github.com/shybyte/drum-cycle-js/blob/fe52a9fd41004ca0600d64a2a191f5f7da9c8f4e/src/dialogue/components/navbar/__test__/navbar.spec.js) [some](https://github.com/futurice/power-ui/blob/85d09645ecadc85bc753ba42fdd841d22d8bdd10/src/components/widgets/AvailabilityFilter/test.js) [examples](https://github.com/yemi/fbm-application/blob/9365dbf67ef16cee5246f128c419c2407fdaf684/app/Widget/FormField/test.js) of Cycle.js tests.

You can also check out the [Testing section](https://github.com/vic/awesome-cyclejs#testing) of the [Awesome Cycle.js](https://github.com/vic/awesome-cyclejs) repo.

*Sidenote: Soon we will be able to write [Marble Tests](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md). Unfortunately this is currently not possible with Cycle.js 6 that only supports [rxjs v4](https://github.com/cyclejs/core/issues/248).
Marble tests is a new feature for rxjs v5. See: [Rxjs testing - is it possible to use marble diagrams also in RxJs 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762776/rxjs-testing-is-it-possible-to-use-marble-diagrams-also-in-rxjs-4)*

Answer (score 1):

There is this guide plus a lot of helpful devs on cycle-core gitter: http://staltz.com/how-to-debug-rxjs-code.html